# Unending Audio Problems

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I keep trying to get my code to play audio for the game I'm working on. The script is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<canvas id="ncanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<html>
        <img id="html5" src="img/smiley.png" />
        <audio id="itn" src="audio/Into_the_night_210420.mp3" />
        <head>
            <script>
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("ncanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("html5");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  var song = document.getElementById("itn"); 
  song.play();
}; 
            </script>
        </head>
</html>
```

But whenever I run the code I get this error message from the Firefox console
NotSupportedError: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.
I tried running it on chrome, but it said it couldn't find the file, even though it was there. Is there something *I'm* doing wrong here, or what? I know the problem isn't accessing the file like my last post, because it clearly works when accessing the smiley.png

Comment: "I know the problem isn't accessing the file", yeah, well, the browser seems to think it is.  Check your assumptions.  Might be a permissions problem.

Comment: years ago people would create web pages which played music upon landing on that link ... to put the kibosh on that harshness browsers were all changed to mute audio / video auto play so to enable media play you need to jump through a hoop ... for details see  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes ... your browser is already telling you this just look at your browser console